# Use of 'suus' in 'ignoranti quem portum petat nullus suus ventus est'

Tags: classical-latin, latin-to-english-translation, grammar-choice, syntax

Seneca, *Epistolae* LXXI: *ignoranti quem portum petat nullus suus ventus est*

commonly translated as 'he who does not know which port he is heading to has no favourable wind'.

Could anyone explain what *suus* is doing? Is it 'no wind of his own' - can the nominative work like that in a dative of possession? Or is there some implication of 'favourable' in it?

Best,
Alexandre

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While not its most common usage, *suus* can also mean something like *proprius*: "their own" as opposed to anyone else's. This is meaning II.B and II.C in Lewis and Short and was especially favored by Seneca, to the point that he gets his own (pun intended) mention in the definition; it also doesn't necessarily require an expressed nominative subject to refer back to.

In particular, look at II.C.5: "According to one's liking, of one's own choice. Of things, favorable." So while this is literally "no wind of their own" (with *suus* referring to the main topic, *ignoranti*) it has the idiomatic meaning of "no wind favorable to (the person who doesn't know)".

Comment: What if "suus" was omitted? Is there a case for dative, "cui", instead of accusative, "quem": "for the ignorant, for he who seeks a port, there is no wind (of his own)"?

Comment: @tony That would change the meaning somewhat, wouldn't it? It would no longer specify what they're ignorant _of_, just saying they're ignorant in general.

Comment: Yes, quite; in the Seneca there is an indirect question - 'ignorant of which port he is headed to'. If he were simply talking about the ignorant in general, the mention of ports would be somewhat strange.